# Stuck....please help to understand how formula works in order to Find the standard deviation in normal distributions

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, statistical-inference, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

A young investment manager tells his client that the probability of making a positive return with his suggested portfolio is 81%. What is the risk (standard deviation) that this investment manager has assumed in his calculation if it is known that returns are normally distributed with a mean of 6.6%? Use Table 1. (Round "z" value to 2 decimal places and final answer to 3 decimal places.)

What is the Standard deviation ?

I have found the z which satisfies this equation, it is .88, however I'm a bit puzzled as to what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Risk and standard deviation are synonymous here.

What the investment manager is saying is that returns follow a normal distribution with mean 6.6 and some unknown variance $\sigma^2$. If we denote the return by $X$ we have
$$ X \sim N(6.6, \sigma^2) $$

The investment manage also tells us that the probability that $X$ is greater than 0 is 81%. Thus we also have
$$ P(X>0) = .81 = 1 - P(X\leq 0) = 1- F_X(0)$$
where $F_x(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF). There are many tables for the CDF of a standard normal distribution (mean=0 and variance=1) so we look to standarize $X$ to follow a $N(0,1)$ distribution.

We can standardize $X$ by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Thus:
$$ Y=\frac{X-6.6}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$$

But recall we know that $P(X>0)=.81 \Rightarrow P(\frac{X-6.6}{\sigma} > \frac{0-6.6}{\sigma})=.81$.
Thus we now have that $P(Y > \frac{-6.6}{\sigma}) = .81$ which we can solve for $\sigma$ using the statistical tables :)